# Insert predefined rows with doctrine

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I am using Doctrine ORM and I want to insert some rows when I update the current schema.

Which is the best way to achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [DoctrineFixturesBundle](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/DoctrineFixturesBundle/index.html) for load initial or test data

> Fixtures are used to load a controlled set of data into a database.

Comment: but why is not recommended for use in production ?

Comment: Fixtures are commonly used for test data and purge data on every loading (however, they have --append option for avoid it)